# Printing two strings with same size and similar names but different number at the end

Tags: java

So I am trying to print two strings in the same for loop and here is what i am working at

```
        ArrayList Arr1 = new ArrayList(15);
        ArrayList Arr2 = new ArrayList(15);

        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        for(int y=0;y < Arr(i).size();y++){

            System.out.println(Arr(i).get(y));
        }
```

Comment: As explained in the linked Q&A `Arr(i)` for `Arr1` or `Arr2` won't work.

Comment: I see thank you, very much